# Pass information to another viewcontroller without pushing or using segues

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios5, nsarray, uitableview

I'm trying to "bookmark" (sort of) an object from one UIViewController so that it then shows on a different UIViewController. Currently, the only way I can get this to work is if I either push to the UIViewController that will display the bookmarks or if I perform a segue which is basically the same thing.

Is there a different approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to send a variable (without loading the view). This is how I do it.

```
DetailViewController *detailvc = [[[DetailViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
detailvc.event = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

And another type of segue I've been doing (without the need of the whole function) i just ask the storyboard to go...

```
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailViewController"];
```

Just don't forget to name the identifier in the sotyboard, properties, identifier.

Hope it helps...
I've been having some trouble re-learning everything with the storyboard as well.